# Why was this edit rolled back?

Tags: discussion, editing

A while ago I edited [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562538/pass-easiest-way-to-synchronize-the-password-store-between-multiple-machines/575152#575152) answer to include a brief description of the link. As I understand it, answers that are just links aren't recommended as the link could break or the contents could change. I noticed that the edit was rolled back today by the original author of the answer. What did I do wrong with the edit?

Comment: I can't speak for the author, but I believe your edit improved the post. You incorporated the actual commands to address the problem. The original answer was indeed link-only.

Comment: I agree, you did a good job. Also, check the newest edit on that question, which improved the formatting on top of your edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You did absolutely nothing wrong. Quite the opposite, your edit was useful and made the post into an actual answer. Without your edit, that wasn't a valid answer for this site. Thanks!

I have now re-applied your edit, keep them coming!